# Inexplicable intermittent buzzing/hissing noise coming from PC at idle, already replaced components

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, noise

Very annoying intermittent buzzing noise coming from my PC at idle. I think it's coming from the PSU area, but I'm not sure. I'm certain it's not coil whine either.

[VIDEO CLIP OF THE NOISE](https://i.imgur.com/fCcCVkF.mp4)

Troubleshootings I've done:

- Turned off all case fans.
- Briefly stopped CPU fan
- Replaced the PSU 3 times.
- Replaced the MOBO once.
- Tested outlet for proper grounding.

Relevant specs:

- Corsair RM850x
- NVIDIA 2060 Super
- AMD Ryzen 5 3600x
- All SSD system

Comment: Is it feasible to try a different, temporary disk drive to eliminate that component?

Comment: I've used ~6 or 8 mm rubber tube as a stethoscope to find noise leaks (holey muffler) under a car. It should be *much* safer to localize the noise source in a PC than under a car. ;-)

Comment: I can't really tell from the video you provided but what I *think* i am hearing is simple radio interference.  It is caused by *something* not being shielded correctly.  Very little you are going to do about it if this is the case (no pun intended).  [This link](https://classroom.synonym.com/block-radio-interference-pc-18484.html) claims to have some tips but I have not verified the text through using any of the tips.  I have had motherboards that did this here and there over the years.